# Super user in LDAP?

Tags: linux, ldap, root

I am running 10 Linux machines that is doing different types of work. The machines are configured to use LDAP authentication so when one user is configured in slapd he can login on all the machines. To make maintenance easier i want to create a root account in slapd so i can use this instead of the local root accounts when installing applications etc. but i am not sure on how to do this. Is it enough to create a user with the name root and gid/uid 0? should the local root be disabled somehow?

I am fully aware that this is normally not a good idea from a security perspective, but as mentioned before this is a special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a UID=0/GID=0 account should be sufficient.

Leave the local *root* user account alone, as if something happens to the LDAP server or the network you'll want "emergency access". Also, I would recommend that the LDAP server itself not be dependent on LDAP for authentication (chicken-and-egg situations).

Make sure you're using SSL/TLS as well.

I would also strongly recommend against doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Use sudo instead of a root account in LDAP. That'll also give you logging of what they did as root.

And +1 on using puppet to manage the servers and have puppet maintain the local copies of /etc/sudoers on all of your servers.

Answer (score 1):

With 10 servers I would look into setting up Puppet and use it manage the applications and configurations.

This is much less error prone and creates repeatable configurations.